# how to distribute protein intake throughout the day

Tags: protein

If I do my workout in the morning right after breakfast. How do I distribute my protein intake through out the day. I am going to be basing my diet on

- Beef
- Baked Beans
- Eggs
- Milk

Also for workout in the morning right after breakfast, what is the best time for carb intake.

Comment: For the average person this doesn't really matter, just have some in each meal and hit your macros. It makes no difference if you take 50g protein in a meal at noon or 3pm..

Answer (score 2):

### How important is nutrient or meal timing?

Under most circumstances and in the grand scheme of things, it's not critical. Of far greater importance is hitting your calorie, macro- and micro-nutrient needs over the course of the day. After that, consistency and commitment should be applied to an appropriate workout plan that suits your performance and/or body goals. If you tend to train in a fasted state, getting your post-workout nutrition in as soon as possible is a good idea, but the first two points (daily diet goals, consistent training) still take precedence. (reddit.com)

[Meal timing does not have significant impact on muscle development](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3879660/). However, your digestive tract may find it easier if you spread your protein evenly over all your meals.

EDIT:

Note: There is no limit to amount of protein you can eat in one sitting: http://examine.com/faq/how-much-protein-can-i-eat-in-one-sitting/

Comment: The trainer at my gym warned me against eating more than about 40 grams of protein in one sitting due to the impact it will have on your kidneys if you do.  For this reason (if it is true) it is very important to spread you protein over all your meals!  30 grams of protein 6 times a day is only 180 grams, which is less than is recommended for me personally.

Comment: @zeeple "For this reason (if it is true):" It is not true, they are talking out of their ass. http://examine.com/faq/how-much-protein-can-i-eat-in-one-sitting/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have achieved what you are seeking to achieve.  First, while I only eat three reasonable-sized "meals" a day, I do consume small amounts of high quality food between meal times.  This is what I strive for in my protein consumption:

```
7 am  - 2 deviled eggs with breakfast
10 am - 1/2 cup of mix nuts
1 pm  - turkey (or ham) sandwich for lunch
4 pm  - yogurt
7 pm  - A portion of fish, usually salmon with dinner
```

My protein does vary quite a bit more than what is pictured here, but this is the gist of it. It is HARD to get enough protein.  According to the head trainer at my gym, you are supposed to get 1 gram per lb. of body weight.  For me that would be 190-ish grams of protein, which is near to impossible (so it seems to me).  So finding ways to consume lots of protein without exceeding your caloric goals is a fine trick to pull off.  Good luck!

Comment: What is this one source and for what goal ? Also how exactly is 70g of protein almost impossible?

Comment: @Brofessor, thank you for challenging me on this.  I double checked with my "source" (which is the head trainer at my gym) and I had it wrong.  He actually recommends 1 gram per lb. of body weight per day and for me that works out to (currently) 194 grams of protein.  Maybe this is not impossible, but it seems daunting to me!  How do you consume so much protein?

Comment: it's definitely not easy but you just need to force it at first until it becomes a habit. when you go grocery shopping, get a bunch of chicken breasts, lean beef, eggs, fish, nuts, whey protein, and make it a lifestyle if it's important to you. You can still get away with less than 194g though, they just recommend 1lb per lbs of bw to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-workout snack of a protein shake plus a complex carbohydrate like brown rice or oats 45 minutes before exercise can give the energy needed to go harder
 during workouts. Try splitting your 3 (large) main meals for 5 smaller ones, eating every 3 hours. Refernece from www.health365.com.au.